# Using gprof with a makefile

Tags: c++, makefile, profiling, gprof

I'm having problems trying to profile my program.

I compile each function seperately like this:

```
function1.o:        function1.cpp
    g++ -g -pg -z -c function1.cpp
```

Then I link together everything like this:

```
exec: function1.o function2.o function3.o main.o  
    g++ -g -pg -z -c -o exec function1.o function2.o function3.o main.o
```

But when I run the program with `./exec` then profile the data with `gprof exec`, I get no profiling data, it says this:

```
granularity: each sample hit covers 4 byte(s) no time accumulated
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you considered using valgrind-callgrind and kcachegrind instead? I had a similar problem, unable to get CMAKE work with gprof, ended up using callgrind. kcachegrind visualization is helpful.

Comment: Why do you think the problem is related to the use of `make`? Do you not see the problem if you compile by hand, without the use of `make`?

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that your program does not run for long enough for gprof to collect any samples.

You could arbitrarily increase the running time by performing the main loop several times.

If you are running on Linux, allow me to also recommend [`perf`](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/) which is a really better profiling tool.